# Recommendation Between HDD and SSD for Web Server

Tags: ssd, hard-disk, server

As the new I.T. guy, the managment ask me for buying an new server for the core proccess application.

This is a web application, "hand made" for a courrier enterprise. As many standart web app, uses a LAMP stack, and the "bottleneck" is the proccessing of the MySQL querys and transactions.

My co-worker told me that a SDD would relief this bottleneck, but at this moment in Colombia, the price of an 400GB is close to $1000 USD (without taxes).

A salesman recomends using two Dell DD 300GB 10K RPM SAS 12Gbps, instead of a SSD. Some "Googling" told that the most important spec of any drive are the IOPS, but i'm confused.

Someone have a close experience using this type of units in an application with **hundreds of concurrent queries**?

Any recommendations on which type of drive is the best option? (*Note the price and capacity*)

Comment: How much does a Dell DD 300gb etc retail for?  In many cases a single SSD can best as many as 5 hdd.